# GPG error in apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt, update-manager

Few minutes ago I ran the following command and it worked fine as always:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then after about 10 minutes, I ran the same command again:

```
sudo apt-get update

Ign http: //fi.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [64.4 kB] 
Ign http: //dl.google.com stable InRelease     
Get:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease [64.5 kB]        
Ign http: //fi.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
E: GPG error: http: //fi.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease:
The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
```

I tried reading every post in askubuntu and stackoverflow and so far nothing.
The following is the only thing that sound rational to me and it didn't solve the issue:

```
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

any suggestions in appreciated.

**UPDATE:** even my Thunderbird was crashing immediately after loading, so I rebooted the computer and I ran the `apt-get update` again and I got:

```
sudo apt update
.
.
.
Fetched 32.2 MB in 10s (3,044kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.sunet.se trusty/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253
```

Comment: Changed something? ufw settings for instance ;)

Comment: Can you increase logging to see which files it fetches, and whether those files actually exist on the server you are downloading from?

Comment: first, try a different server like archive.ubuntu.com instead

Comment: @tripleee your comment is valid but before I get the chance to read it, I rebooted the computer and situation changed, logging would not be helpful at this point. (I updated the post accordingly)

Comment: Firstly, you should check your date and clock.

Comment: @davidbaumann date and time were correct at the time of this incident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did to solve my question after rebooting and googling more:

1. `reboot` (Reboot the computer)
2. `sudo apt-get update` (this will give you a warning about expired keys)
3. `apt-key list | grep expired` (as suggested in [another post](https://serverfault.com/a/615362/113597)) and I got:

   > pub   2048R/E084DAB9 2010-10-19 [expired: 2015-10-18]
4. copy the key ID is the bit after the `/` (in my case E084DAB9)
5. `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net E084DAB9` (remember to change the key ID of this command to the one you get from your computer)
6. `sudo apt update`
7. `sudo apt upgrade`